# Well written Perl Open Source to learn from?

Tags: perl, open-source

is there any well written perl open source out there (not using any kinda of framework) that i could use as sample for learning and good pratice of the perl...

I've searched around and found many things for PHP, but nothing in perl that uses no framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know of a good project to recommend, but the book [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735) is excellent for improving the quality of the Perl code you write.

Comment: @ire_and_curses thanks i will make sure to read it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried browsing [CPAN](http://cpan.org)?  You can find code there doing pretty much anything, and many distributions post links to their github repositories, so you can follow along in the development process.

[CPAN Ratings](http://cpanratings.perl.org/) has reviews and rankings of a large number of releases, which helps you differentiate between good releases and bad ones, but being able to make this determination for yourself would be best, which you get through learning and experience.

Comment: Well i do make use of CPAN but i dont belive my level of coding with perl allows me to know which are well written code and which arent ... i could say i am semi-intermediary with it or so... If you could possible link me some goodies i would appreciate it very much. What i meant to say is that i've seen lots of coding with perl while i would think some are well written and clear in the end it could have been something not really for good pratice ... can't put this well into words...

Comment: @Prix: you'd probably get more out of reading some books first: *Learning Perl*, *Intermediate Perl*, and *Mastering Perl*, which introduce you do everything you need to know to tell good CPAN modules from bad ones (and also show you a lot of the good ones that will be in your toolbox). See [What comes next after *Learning Perl*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555429/what-comes-next-after-learning-perl)  Also, [cpanratings](http://cpanratings.perl.org/) has rankings and reviews of CPAN releases.

Comment: @Ether - Isn't 'CPAN ratings' more concerned with usefulness than code quality? I don't think pointing at the entirety of CPAN is particularly helpful - there's plenty of idiosyncratic, outdated, or downright horrible code there. Even though that same code is also useful, there's really no way for a beginner to identify the good practices from the bad.

Comment: that was what i was thinking to myself, ofc reading books will help me out and i do every time i am able to but i also belive that reading well written codes does too... but unfortunatly considering my level and what i previously said i would rather appreciate a direct link to a project rather then sereval modules where i can't really define it myself like ire_and_curses said. To be fairly honest that is why i was looking for an open source not using a framework.

Comment: CPAN Ratings is related to usefulness (as it is an end user fed benchmark), the CPANTS score (http://cpants.perl.org/) on the other hand is related to code quality (various static analysis techniques).  CPANTS combined with the output of perlcritic should give a decent metric